# Where can I find more information on special sequences in 'hash' part of URL, I.E. #:~:text=start%20of%20selection,end%20of%20selection

Tags: url, hash, standards

I just noticed, that when Google serves links in search results, it adds a special segment in hash part of url, which causes browser (Edgium in this case) to highlight certain text on the page i.e.:

*SO url formatter messes up the link, so it needs to be pasted directly into address-bar* `https://www.linuxtechi.com/nc-ncat-command-examples-linux-systems/#:~:text=ncat%20or%20nc%20is%20networking,with%20scripts%20or%20other%20programs.`

The part `#:~:text=ncat%20or%20nc%20is%20networking,with%20scripts%20or%20other%20programs.` will cause browser to find and highlight text between `ncat or nc is networking utility` and `with scripts or other programs.` on the opened page. I've never heard about anything like this and can't find any information about it in Google or MDN. Is there any standard \ spec \ manual \ tutorial about this and similar special hash sequences in Urls?

Comment: Seems like your browser has a bug or a special feature (you decide). Did you test it with other more popular browsers?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Somehow i don`t think Google relies on bugs in my browser when generating search result Urls?

Comment: @ArtjomB. SO formatter messed up the link, i've updated the post to have a raw version.

Comment: Sorry about that. Now I know what you mean.